# How to construct a data structure using a bytearray inside a Substrate Pallet?

Tags: serde, serde-json

I have a struct declaration in Substrate Pallet as follows

Method implementations are inside Uniques pallet

The flow

- an NFT gets minted
- Sets Attributes for the minted NFT
- attribute value passed as a JSON
- Inside the split method, requires to get the attribute for the NFT
- modify current_fraction to another value
- Save the attribute

Uniques pallet's set_attribute function

```
pub fn set_attribute(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            collection: T::CollectionId,
            maybe_item: Option<T::ItemId>,
            key: BoundedVec<u8, T::KeyLimit>,
            value: BoundedVec<u8, T::ValueLimit>,
        )
```

So if I pass a JSON like `{ current_fraction: 1 }` from polkadot App, the value of  `value: BoundedVec<u8, T::ValueLimit>,` is `[123, 34, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 95, 102, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 34, 58, 49, 125]` ,

So this is the value I need to retrieve , reconstruct the object, modify its value and saves it

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, Default, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
pub struct RealEstateValues {
    pub current_fraction: u32,
}
```

I have a function to split an Asset written in the same substrate pallet as follows

```
#[pallet::call_index(26)]
        #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::split())]
        pub fn split(
            sender_origin: OriginFor<T>,
            collection_id: T::CollectionId,
            item_id: T::ItemId,
            key: BoundedVec<u8, T::KeyLimit>,
            num_of_splits: u32,
        ) -> DispatchResult {

            // TODO: Move this to config or storage
            let property_key = "realEstateData";
            let maximum_splits: u32 = 52u32;

            // ensure!(num_of_splits.le(&maximum_splits), Error::<T, I>::ExceedsMaxSplits);

            let property_key: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<32>>  =
                BoundedVec::try_from(property_key.as_bytes().to_vec()).map_err(|_| Error::<T, I>::ErrorConvertingKey)?;

            ensure!(key == property_key, Error::<T, I>::InvalidKey);

            let origin = ensure_signed(sender_origin.clone())?;

            let item_metadata = ItemMetadataOf::<T, I>::get(collection_id, item_id).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::MetadataMissingForItem)?;
            let item_attribute = Attribute::<T, I>::get((collection_id, Some(item_id), &key)).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::AttributesMissingForItem)?;



            let real_estate_value = item_attribute.0.clone();

            let item_attribute_vec = real_estate_value.to_vec();
            let real_estate_value_json: RealEstateValues = Decode::decode(&mut &item_attribute_vec[..]).map_err(|_| Error::<T, I>::InvalidPropertyAttributes)?;

            //  ***********************************************************************************

            // ***********************************************************************************

            ensure!(num_of_splits.saturating_mul(real_estate_value_json.current_fraction).le(&maximum_splits), Error::<T, I>::ExceedsMaxSplits);

            let new_real_estate_values = RealEstateValues {
                current_fraction: num_of_splits,

            };

            let new_real_estate_values_bounded_vec: BoundedVec<u8, T::ValueLimit> =  Encode::encode(&new_real_estate_values).try_into().unwrap();//new_real_estate_values.encode().try_into().unwrap();
            //   let p = serde_json::to_string(&new_real_estate_values).unwrap();
            // // let new_real_estate_values_bounded_vec: BoundedVec<u8, T::ValueLimit> = p.as_bytes();
            let  mut current_item_id = CurrentItemItByCollection::<T, I>::get(collection_id).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::UnknownItem)?;

            let parent_item_id = current_item_id;

            let mut new_item_ids = Vec::with_capacity(num_of_splits as usize);

            for _ in 0..num_of_splits  {

                let  next_nft_id = <T as Config<I>>::ItemId::from(current_item_id.into() + 1);

                new_item_ids.push(next_nft_id);

                Self::do_mint(collection_id, next_nft_id, origin.clone(), |collection_details| {
                    if collection_details.issuer != origin {
                        return Err(Error::<T, I>::NoPermission.into());
                    }
                    Ok(())
                })?;

                Self::deposit_event(Event::NewItemMinted { collection_id, item_id: next_nft_id, owner:origin.clone() });

                Self::set_metadata(
                    sender_origin.clone(),
                    collection_id,
                    next_nft_id,
                    item_metadata.data.clone(),
                    false,
                )?;


                Self::set_attribute(
                    sender_origin.clone(),
                    collection_id,
                    Some(next_nft_id),
                    key.clone(),
                    new_real_estate_values_bounded_vec.clone(),
                )?;

                current_item_id = next_nft_id;
            }
            CurrentItemItByCollection::<T, I>::set(collection_id, Some(current_item_id));

            Self::deposit_event(Event::ItemSplit {
                parent_collection_id: collection_id,
                parent_item_id: item_id,
                num_of_splits,
                new_item_ids,
                owner: origin.clone(),
            });

            // Burn parent NFT on success

            Self::do_burn(collection_id, parent_item_id, |collection_details, details| {
                let is_permitted = collection_details.admin == origin || details.owner == origin;
                ensure!(is_permitted, Error::<T, I>::NoPermission);
                Ok(())
            })?;

            Self::deposit_event(Event::Burned { collection: collection_id, item: parent_item_id, owner: origin });

            Ok(())

        }
```

This is the corresponding test

```
#[test]
fn split_should_work() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        Balances::make_free_balance_be(&1, 100_000);
        let key_str = "realEstateData";
        let key_bounded_vec: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<50>> =key_str.as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap();

        let mut item_id = 1u32;
        let collection_id = 1u32;

        println!("real_estate_values: {:?}", real_estate_values);

        let json_data = serde_json::json!({
            "current_fraction": 1,
        });

        // Serialize the JSON data to bytes
        let serialized_json = serde_json::to_vec(&json_data).unwrap();


        
        let real_estate_values_bounded_vec: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<50>> = serialized_json.try_into().unwrap();

        // let real_estate_values_bounded_vec: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<50>> = serde_json::to_string(&real_estate_values).unwrap().as_bytes().to_vec().try_into().unwrap();
        // let real_estate_values_bounded_vec: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<50>> = Encode::encode(&real_estate_values).try_into().unwrap();
        println!("real_estate_values_bounded_vec: {:?}", real_estate_values_bounded_vec);
        let real_estate_value_json: RealEstateValues = Decode::decode(&mut &real_estate_values_bounded_vec[..]).unwrap();
        println!("real_estate_value_json: {:?}", real_estate_value_json);

        assert_ok!(Uniques::create(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), collection_id, 1));

        assert_ok!(Uniques::mint(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), collection_id, item_id, 1));

        // Sets Metadata
        assert_ok!(Uniques::set_metadata(
            RuntimeOrigin::signed(1),
            collection_id,
            item_id,
            bvec![0, 0],
            false
        ));

        // Sets Attributes
        assert_ok!(Uniques::set_attribute(
            RuntimeOrigin::signed(1),
            collection_id,
            Some(item_id),
            key_bounded_vec.clone(),
            real_estate_values_bounded_vec
        ));

        assert_ok!(Uniques::set_price(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), collection_id, item_id, Some(400), None));
        assert_ok!(Uniques::set_metadata(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), collection_id, item_id, bvec![42, 42], false));


        assert_ok!(Uniques::split(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), collection_id, item_id, key_bounded_vec.clone(), 4));

        item_id += 1;

        assert_ok!(Uniques::set_metadata(
            RuntimeOrigin::signed(1),
            collection_id,
            item_id,
            bvec![0, 0],
            false
        ));

        assert_noop!(
            Uniques::split(RuntimeOrigin::signed(1), collection_id, item_id, key_bounded_vec, 14),
            Error::<Test>::ExceedsMaxSplits
        );
    });
}
```

So when I do

```
let real_estate_value_json: RealEstateValues = Decode::decode(&mut &item_attribute_vec[..]).map_err(|_| Error::<T, I>::InvalidPropertyAttributes)?;
```

when I try to use serde or serde_json dependency it throws an error when Im compiling substrate

it gives this error

```
  error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `std` (which `serde_json` depends on): `panic_impl`.
    |
    = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on)
    = note: first definition in `sp_io`
```

If I use this method in serde

````
let real_estate_value_json: RealEstateValues = from_slice(&item_attribute_vec)
                .map_err(|_| Error::<T, I>::InvalidPropertyAttributes)?;
    ```

It incorrectly sets current_fraction value 
How to fix this issue?
````

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite understand what you are doing, but it looks like a mixing of the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits from `serde` with the `Encode` and `Decode` traits from `SCALE`.
There should be no JSON or `serde` needed in your runtime, just SCALE decode. It is simpler and has deterministic encoding for values.

Some example:

```rust
#[test]
fn encode_decode() {
    use codec::{Encode, Decode};
    use sp_runtime::Perbill;

    #[derive(Encode, Decode)]
    struct Value {
        current_fraction: Perbill,
    }
    let value = Value { current_fraction: Perbill::from_percent(10) };

    // encoding is infallible
    let encoded_value = Value::encode(&value);

    // Decode the value again:
    match Value::decode(&mut &encoded_value[..]) {
        Ok(decoded_value) => {
            assert_eq!(decoded_value.current_fraction, Perbill::from_percent(10))
        },
        Err(e) => /* handle error ... */,
    }
}
```

Also note that there exist types like `Perbill` or `FixedU64` to represent fractions for your convenience.

Comment: Value submitted as a HexEncoded json. and stored in a bounded vec, if you try to decode this it gives incorrect results for values

Comment: I have updated question